# How to make slidedown after clicking an image?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a simple page with some images. My idea is that - user click image, and from this image slides a list. When you click e.g an Audi logo, there should be shown a list with Audi models, BMW - BMW models etc. I know how to do that on div, but I have problem understanding how to do that on specific image.

Comment: So your able to do it when you do a click on div but not on image? Why dont you just wrap your image in a `div` or in a `link` tag? Can you show us what you've tried and where exactly in your code you are having an issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.